# C# GetResponseAsync() : How to use correctly

Tags: c#, exception, asynchronous

I'm developing an application using the Twitch API, and I tried to use asynchronous request.

I test before with a synchronous request, like this :

```
private async static Task<string> generalRequest(string url, string method, object payload = null, string accessToken = null, API api = API.V5, string clientId = null)
{
    url = appendClientId(url, ClientId);

    var request = WebRequest.CreateHttp(url);
    request.Method = method;
    request.ContentType = "application/json";
   
    var response = request.GetResponse();
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        string data = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
        return data;
    }
}
```

It works great but this is not asynchronous.

I tried with `GetResponseAsync()` like this :

```
using (var response2 = await request.GetResponseAsync())
{
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(response2.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        string data = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
        return data;
    }
}
```

However, it never got through the first `using`, and I got these exceptions :

> Exception levée : 'System.Net.WebException' in mscorlib.dll
>
> Exception levée : 'System.Exception' in LivestreamerTwitchViewer.exe
>
> Exception levée : 'System.Exception' in mscorlib.dll

So what I did wrong?

How do I use `GetResponseAsync()` correctly?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Show async method signature please. Wouldn't hurt to see full body as well.

Comment: @Karolis - my only guess is that the OP is using the same method as before, but swapping out the `var request = request.GetResponse()` down to the `return` statement with the `using(...)` statement in the second code block. Unless the method and/or rest of body is different, I would imagine that posting the second attempt's full method body would be unnecessary.

Comment: @GeoffJames If that is the case, then only issue I can think of is fault in API, which is unlikely. That is reasoning behind my request. Also regarding Async/Async methods signature of method matter in cases where you return different underlying  type of tasks, although a long shot. :)

Comment: @Karolis - I disagree. Choosing between a synchronous/asynchronous request in one's code would not be discriminated by an API. It would be nothing to do with the API itself, unless the request itself was indeed altered slightly in the asynchronous version of the method.

Comment: @0_yami_0 - is it possible that you are able to inspect the `System.Net.WebException` you are receiving and see if there is a slightly more descript error message in there, that you could post in your question?

Comment: @GeoffJames - Okay, this is resolved, I just forgot to include in the URL the ClientId needed for the API, sorry for disturbing.